# How to scale a bitmap using ImageData

Tags: canvas

I have the following code:

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const imageData = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(image.bitmap.data), 
  image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height);
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

This works for showing a canvas on the pixel level, how can I scale each pixel to be 10x10 for example? I've tried some code on other answers but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to remove the width and height from the canvas element in the HTML.